# setConsumerRebalanceListener how to get consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I use spring-kafka 1.1.3.RELEASE and kafka-clients 0.10.0.0 and I want setConsumerRebalanceListener in factory like this, but I don't know how to get consumer to save consumer partition. Thanks your any suggestion!

```
@Bean   

KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
        kafkaListenerBatchContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
            factory.setConcurrency(3);
            factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
            factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(execD());
            factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

            factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);

            factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
                    for (TopicPartition partition:collection){
                    //TODO how to get consumer?    saveOffsetInExternalStore(consumer,partition.partition());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> collection) {
                     for (TopicPartition partition:collection){
                    //TODO how to get consumer?      
                       consumer.seek();
                    }
                }
            });
            factory.setBatchListener(true);

            return factory;
        }
```

I use factory like that:

```
 @KafkaListener(group = "CID_alikafka_B024",topicPattern = "data_.*",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerBatchContainerFactory")
    public void receive2(List<String> data,Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) List<String> topicName,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) List<String> messageKeys) {
        logger.info("start of batch receive");

    }
```

I know spring kafka 2.1.9 have ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener like this,but i want use spring kafka 1.1.3.RELEASE to compatible kafka 0.10.0.0 ,we kafka is version is 0.10.0.0

```
containerProperties.setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevokedBeforeCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // acknowledge any pending Acknowledgments (if using manual acks)
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsRevokedAfterCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // ...
            store(consumer.position(partition));
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // ...
            consumer.seek(partition, offsetTracker.getOffset() + 1);
        // ...
    }
});
```

My pom is:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- exclude kafka version problem-->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.1.3 is extremely old in the fast-moving world of Apache Kafka. You can't access the consumer there.

Spring for Apache Kafka added the `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` in 2.0. The current version is 2.1.8.

Newer versions of the Kafka clients can talk to older brokers if you can't upgrade the broker (but you should, 0.10.0.0 is also very old).

See [the documenation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#rebalance-listeners).

Also see the [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) which explains about compatibility. From the confluent page:

> Broker 0.10.0
>   Basic client compatibility:
>   Java: clients <= 0.10.0 or >= 0.10.2